# Rails 3 permissions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have a rails app and each user has a profile that has videos, photos, etc. Everything works fine but I am unable to separate a profile from another user profile.

**Example:** 
I have two users Jack and bob. Jack profile url is *jack.mysite.com* and bob profile url is *bob.mysite.com*. When jack uploads a video and I visit the url *jack.mysite.com/videos* I would only like to see jack videos and not bob videos and vice versa.

How can I tell rails to only show me a users uploads(videos,photos etc) when visiting their profile url?

Comment: What are you using for authentication (devise)? how are you storing your photos and videos? if you store your media in a model with a "belongs_to user" and you used devise, you would just query for videos that belong to "current_user".

Comment: I am using devise and can you write out an example query if you do not mind?

Comment: I'll assume that you have a "Media" model, which contains your photos and videos, and that you have "belongs_to user" in your Media model. Then you would have a column called "user_id" in your Media model and you could do something like this: Media.where(user_id: current_user).
But that isn't going to be super helpful unless you happen to have the exact setup I was assuming.

Comment: a user has a profile which a profile belongs_to :user and has_many :videos, Photos, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your videos and other profile related stuff has a belongs_to relation with the user model.

When you visit a url like jack.site.nl and you want to only show jacks stuff, you need to pass the sub domain as a constraint in your routes and pick up the param in the receiving controller. You should be able to do something like this in your controller:

```
user = User.find_by_username(params[:subdomain])
@videos = Video.where(user_id: user.id)
```

Checkout one of the subdomain Railscasts for more details
http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=subdomain

When you need to restrict each users data you should checkout http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

Answer (score 1):

This is a little abstract, but here's what you have to do:

**1. Grab the current user's profile because it has the association to videos and photos.**

```
# with devise gem:
current_profile = User.profile # if your user has a profile
# otherwise something messy like this maybe:
# current_profile = Profile.where(user_id: current_user).first
```

**2. Grab the videos and photos which belonging to the current user's profile.**

```
current_users_videos = Video.where( profile_id: current_profile )
current_users_photos = Photo.where( profile_id: current_profile )
# writing a scope on Video and Photo would be cleaner, btw
```